# My desktop is empty, I can only see the wallpaper. How can I fix it?

Tags: unity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn’t load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

I logged in to ubuntu and this is all I see.

[image: Empty Desktop]

I opened up Firefox through the terminal to get here.

I remember swapping hard-drives that had Windows 8 installed in it. And after putting back this hard drive I didn't let Ubuntu start properly and restarted to log in to Windows 8.

Comment: install ccsm, `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager python-compizconfig`. In terminal type `ccsm`, Now in the plugins, check whether `unity plugin` is checked or not. If not, please check it.

Comment: I deleted your second question. Feel free to create another question post with your second question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/q/17381/25656)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to reset compiz and unity settings. Switch to a text terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1. Login there, and issue the following commands.

```
gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1
unity --reset
```

You better reboot now

```
sudo reboot now
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: will not work for 12.10